# Is there a plugin to support simple navigation in yaml?

Tags: filetype-yaml

I've been unable to find plugin support for simple navigation to "next/previous with same indentation" (e.g `[[` and `]]`) in yaml. I have folding supported, but I'd like to navigate without using folds.

I feel like this shouldn't be hard, but I'm just not looking in the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `foldmethod=indent` you can use <kbd>[z</kbd> and <kbd>]z</kbd> for moving to start/end of current fold.
And <kbd>zj</kbd> and <kbd>zk</kbd> for moving to start/end of down/upwards fold.

These might interest you:

- [github.com/wellle/context.vim](https://github.com/wellle/context.vim)
- [github.com/haya14busa/vim-edgemotion](https://github.com/haya14busa/vim-edgemotion)

Answer (score 1):

I quite like [vim-indentwise](https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-indentwise) for this sort of thing.